# I can't add string to all value an array

Tags: laravel, api

**I am new in developing ِAPi from laravel i need to insert path app into value an array**

```
   $halls = DB::table('halls')
            ->join('imagas','halls.id','=','imagas.id_Halls')
            ->select('halls.id','halls.hall_name','halls.hall_adress','halls.hall_details','price_hours','price_int','halls.hall_name','imagas.image_path')->where('halls.id',157)
            ->get();

    $results=[];

    foreach ($halls as $hall) {

    $array=json_decode($hall->image_path,true);
    if (is_array($array))
    {
       $hall->image_path = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Imaga_halls/'.$array;

        }
        array_push($results, $hall);
    }

    return response()->json($results);

    }
```

**the error is**

> ErrorException: Array to string conversion

Comment: what is `$hall->image_path`?

Comment: it is column rustle from database  Includes paths image an array

Comment: can u post one of the value?

Comment: it desplay this "image_path": [
            "1579635536.jpg",
            "1579635535.png"
        ]  but  i want display like this ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/Imaga_halls/1579635536.jpg",
        
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/Imaga_halls/1579635535.png"]

Comment: Can you try converting `$array` to a string first then save it in a new variable. After that, concatenate the `url` with the new string.

Comment: I have posted my answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$hall->image_path = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Imaga_halls/'.$array;
```

You are trying to concat an array to a string here.

Comment: here I want to insert the path to all value in array

Answer (score 0):

After `get()` method on query builder, you will get the collection, so that you can use `map()` function to loop every `hall` object.

And concat prefix path with image:

```php
    $halls = DB::table('halls')
               ->join('imagas','halls.id','=','imagas.id_Halls')
               ->select('halls.id','halls.hall_name','halls.hall_adress','halls.hall_details','price_hours','price_int','halls.hall_name','imagas.image_path')
               ->where('halls.id',157)
               ->get();

    $results = $halls->map(function($hall) {
        $array = json_decode($hall->image_path, true);
        $hall->image_path = collect($array)->map(function($image) {
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Imaga_halls/'.$image;
        })->toArray();
        return $hall;   
    });

    return response()->json($results);
```